# Characterization of sequence in $l^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the space of integrable sequence $\ell^1(\mathbb{R}) = \left\{ u \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \ |\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty |u_n| < \infty \right\}$. I wonder if it possible that
$$
\forall u \in \ell^1(\mathbb{R}), \quad \lim_{n\to \infty} n u_n = 0
$$
If not, can you give a counterexample ? And in such case, is it possible that the subspace $\left\{ u\in \ell^1(\mathbb{R}) \ | \ \lim_{n\to\infty} n u_n = 0\right\}$ is closed in $\ell^1(\mathbb{R})$ (and then is a Banach space) ?

For the first question, I tried a proof by contradiction, trying to extract a subsequence which is not in $\ell^1(\mathbb{R})$ but I find it hard to do it rigorously.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
u_n=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }n\text{ is not a power of }2,\\
k^{-2} &  \text{if }n=2^k.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\sum u_n<\infty$ but $\limsup n\,u_n=\infty$.

The subspace of all sequences such that $n\,u_n\to0$ contains the subspace of all sequences with finitely many non zero terms, which is dense in $\ell^1$. It follows that it is not closed.

Comment: Nice counterexample, thanks for your answer !